# How do I save an edited image in HDR Efex Pro on MacOS (High Sierra)?

Tags: apple-aperture

I am still using Aperture and Nik Collection on my Mac (High Sierra). Nik Collection partially works. Silver Efex is working fine but HDR Efex does not save the edited photo, but the original one instead.

Are you facing the same issue. Did you fix it anyhow?

Comment: Make sure you grab the last versions of them all, before DxO rework them & start charging - https://www.google.com/nikcollection/

Comment: Yes, I have Nikcollection 1.2.11 (quite old in fact). I was happy to pay for it. Google provided it for free but stopped the developement. I am looking forward to DxO.

Comment: Ah, OK - last HDR version is 2.2.24 - wonder if there might be a functional difference? It's the last of the free, so worth a shot. tbh, I've yet to find an HDR plug/suite that I'm totally happy with; I'm still looking around, but it's not something I do often so the need isn't too pressing.

Comment: It is a strange versioning, HDR 2.2.24 is part of Nikcollection 1.2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found a work around, see https://www.flickr.com/groups/581278@N21/discuss/72157661264159120/

Uncheck “Automatically reimport.”, save elsewhere and import manually to the Aperture. It is annoying but it works.